# Capture transcript of program with redirected input and output

Tags: bash, scripting

A typical interaction for a program I've written might look like this:

```
Enter command: a_command
Completed a command

Enter command: another_command
Completed another command
```

I typically run my program like `./program < input.txt`, where `input.txt` would contain:

```
a_command
another_command
```

I want to be able to capture the entire interaction (not just the output) like above. How can I do this with bash?

EDIT: `program` is a binary (specifically, it's in C++), not a bash script. I have access to the source code, but I'd like to do this without having to modify the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print the input after the corresponding prompt, you need to know when the program is waiting for input. There's no way to tell from observing the running program: you can't distinguish a program that's waiting for input on stdin from a program that's waiting for something else (network, disk, computation, …).

So the process to obtain a transcript which would look like interactive use has to go like this:

- Launch the program.
- Wait for — and recognize — the first prompt.
- Display and send the input to the first prompt.
- Ditto with the second prompt for input and all subsequent ones.
- Quit when the program exits.

The de facto standard tool to script this is [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). The script would look something like this (warning: not working code, typed directly in my browser):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set transcript_file [open "transcript" wb]
spawn myprogram
expect "Enter command:"
puts -nonewline $transcript_file $expect_out(buffer)
send "a_command\r"
puts -nonewline $transcript_file "a_command\r"
puts -nonewline $transcript_file $expect_out(buffer)
send "another_command\r"
puts -nonewline $transcript_file "another_command\r"
puts -nonewline $transcript_file $expect_out(buffer)
…
expect eof
close $transcript_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `set -x` in your program file.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x #echo on

ls $PWD
```

This expands all variables and prints the full commands before output of the command.

output:

```
+ ls /home/user/
file1.txt file2.txt
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853843) from Stackoverflow for more similar flags for the set command.

Comment: This does not work. When I run my program as I specified in the question with redirected input, `./program < input.txt`, only `./program` is printed. I still do not see the contents of `input.txt` with the output.

Comment: The `set -x` needs to be the first line of your `program.sh`.

Comment: `program` is a binary, not a script

Comment: Isn't the entire interaction being shown on the terminal? Also, are those `scanf` / `stdin` statements?

Comment: the output is shown on the terminal, but when I redirect input with `<`, the input is just fed into the program and not shown.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do so without modifying the program itself.